# Build react app multiple times with different environment variables

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I have a development environment file `.env.development` and a production `.env` file for my React web app.

The `.env.development` has a value `REACT_APP_NAME=My Test App` and the `.env` file has the value `REACT_APP_NAME=My Blue App`.

This works if there is only one customer (called Blue) that uses my app. The `.env` has the customer address and more customer specific values as well.

Now I want to deliver the app to multiple customers with multiple customer specifications in multiple env files.

My idea is to store customer specific env files:

- .env.blue
- .env.red
- .env.yellow

When I now (somehow) build the app, I'll get three folders

- build_blue
- build_red
- build yellow

and each folders consumed the specific environment for the build.

Is this somehow possible?

My current workaround would be:

- Rename `.env.blue` to `.env`
- yarn build
- publish to ftp server
- Rename `.env` to `.env.blue`
- Rename `.env.red` to `.env`
- yarn build
- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build a little shell script that does the job.
I'd like to share it, as someone else forces the same solution:

```
mv .env env

for CURR in .env.red .env.blue .env.yellow
do
    mv $CURR .env
    yarn build
    mv build build_$CURR
    cp .env build_$CURR/.env
    mv .env $CURR
done

mv env .env
```

After that you can load the different build folders to the different servers and move the .env file to the root.